# Typescript export default always executing

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongoose

As a beginner in node js I cannot wrap my head around following problem.

```
import { createSchema, Type, typedModel } from "ts-mongoose";

const CompanySchema = createSchema(
  {
    companyName: Type.string({ required: true, unique: true })
  },
  {
    timestamps: true
  }
);

const Company = typedModel("Company", CompanySchema);

export { CompanySchema, Company };
```

This all works just fine until one point. When attempting to import this file.

```
import {CompanySchema, Company} from "./Company";
```

It executes typeModel method and stores the schema as expected. However, any other import of this file Company.ts reruns this method typeModel again. Which then fails because I can register schema with the name only once. How could I prevent of reruning this and still keep access to this object?

What would be general approach to this in order to keep access to both CompanySchema and Company object(as they will be later used in another schema as a reference)?

Answer (score -2):

I don't know what the createSchema and typedModel are( if they are functions created by you or part of mongoose, the versions of mongoose ive worked with didnt have these functions )

...but I think you should not "createSchema" but define it instead.

e.g

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// define schema
const messageSchema = Schema({
    sender: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    recipient: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    deletedAt: { type: Date, default: undefined },
    readAt: { type: Date, default: undefined},
    message: { type: String, maxlength: 5000 }
});

// create a model based on that schema
const Message = mongoose.model('Message', messageSchema);

// Export the message model ... not the schema

module.exports.Message = Message;
```

Comment: op is using `ts-mongoose`